# JQuery nextAll reading all the input fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have following html:

```
<input type="text" id="entry1" value="1" />
<input type="text" id="entry2" value="2" />
<input type="text" id="entry3" value="3" />
<input type="text" id="entry4" value="4" />
<input type="text" id="entry5" value="5" />
<input type="text" id="entry6" value="6" />
<input type="text" id="entry7" value="7" />

<input type="button" id="test" value="Test 1" />

..
$('#test').click(function () {
  var entrys = $(':text[id != "entry5"]').nextAll(':text');
});
```

What I was hoping was that it would return entry6, entry7 only.  But what I'm getting is
basically all the text input fields.  What am I doing wrong? Or am I using `nextAll()` incorrectly?  I'm using entry5 as an example but what I want to do is get the fields only after a certain input text id.  So if I set it to entry6 only return entry7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You meant to use `=` instead of `!=`:

```
var entrys = $('input:text[id="entry5"]').nextAll('input:text');
```

However, [Arun's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16197393/901048) is simpler and more appropriate in this case.

Comment: Your right that fixed it.  After looking at the code it makes better sense now.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `id` selector since you have an id for the input field. You problem was you were using `!=` instead of `=`.

In this case you don't have to use attribute selector since you are using `id` as the attribute, you have a built in `id` selector.

```
$('#test').click(function () {
    var entrys = $('#entry5').nextAll(':text');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/FYZeY/)

Comment: This is definitely cleaner too.  Thanks